# MacBook does not sleep when lid is closed while connected to an external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, high-sierra, sleep-wake, closed-clamshell

I am trying to disable the "clam shell" mode of my MacBook (13" early 2011 Unibody) running macOS High Sierra. I want the computer to sleep when the lid is closed even when it is connected to power and an external monitor.

After disabling SIP I was able to edit the com.apple.Boot.plist file and add `Kernel Flags iog=0x0`as I have done in previous version of macOS, but the setting doesn't appear to work in High Sierra.

Also
`sudo nvram boot-args=iog=0x0` from (recovery mode) terminal writes the entry, but also has no effect.

Is there any way to achieve lid close > sleep with external monitor and AC power in High Sierra?